# making more precis to choose Dateandtime in Mysql

Tags: mysql, date

In my database I have table which is called appointments and there I have `id,name of the buyer,time when I made appointment and time for the appointment`. So my question is how to make  `mariadb` to show me all the `datesandtime` after `time when I made appointment` for dateandtime for the appointment. Because you can not make appointment for buying something for the date that is before the date when I made the appointment.

Comment: You want the list of appointment for specific time period? Please clear your question.

Comment: no, i need when i fill my  table with informations that when i click on atribute time for the appointment to show me date picker only dates that are after date and time that i choose in the prevoius atribute time when i made appointment

Comment: You can do it using php code you can not validate data at the time of table creation, you have to validate your data at the time of insertion. you can set size of column and type of column. In the MSSQL or Oracal, there are triggers that can handle this at database level, but in mysql not sure you are doing good practice.

Comment: Are you just trying to write a query to see appointments after a certain time? If so, please show example input data and desired output results, or otherwise clarify your question. The text and title are currently very vague.

Comment: It's also not at all clear what "buying something for the date" means, when the only times you talked about were for appointments. Is the person buying an appointment? Or are they making an appointment to buy something? Because that would change which "date" you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using php code you can not validate data at the time of table creation, you have to validate your data at the time of insertion. you can set size of column and type of column. In the MSSQL or Oracle, there are triggers that can handle this at database level, but in mysql not sure you are doing good practice.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but that is not something that fits me..i am trying to find the solution at level when i manually import in phpmyadmin data.